# Error post using begincollectionitem MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using begincollectionitem component, and when trying to save data is giving error at line `db.SaveChanges();`. I use MVC 4 e Razor.

This message error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

A minha implementação é esta:

### Model

```
public class ProdutoPadrao : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  public int ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
  public string Descricao { get; set; }
  [Display(Name = "Detalhe")]
  public string Detalhe { get; set; } 
  public virtual ICollection<ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica> ListaProdutoCaracteristica { get; set; }    
}

public class ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica : IEntidadeBase
{
  [Key]
  public int ProdutoPadraoCaracteristicaID { get; set; }
  public int ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }
  public string Descricao { get; set; }
  public int TipoCaracteristicaID { get; set; }    
  [ForeignKey("ProdutoPadraoID")]
  public virtual ProdutoPadrao ProdutoPadrao { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller GET

```
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Detalhar(int id)
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var produtoPadrao = db.ProdutoPadrao.Include("ListaProdutoCaracteristica").Where(w => w.ProdutoPadraoID == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        var retorno = EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(produtoPadrao, TipoAcao.Visualizar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica = new SelectList(ListagemPadrao.ListaTipoCaracteristica(), "Key", "Texto");
        ViewBag.ListaUnidadeMedida = new SelectList(db.UnidadeMedida.ToListERP().Select(l => new ItemLPesquisa { Key = l.UnidadeMedidaID, Texto = l.Descricao }).ToArray(), "Key", "Texto");
        return View(produtoPadrao);
    }
}
```

### Controller POST

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ControleDeAcesso(TipoAcao.Normal)]
public ActionResult Detalhar(string btnSubmit, ProdutoPadrao model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        return View(model);
    }

    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var produtoPadrao = db.ProdutoPadrao.Include("ListaProdutoCaracteristica").Where(w => w.ProdutoPadraoID == model.ProdutoPadraoID).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
        var retorno = FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.ValidarRegistro(produtoPadrao, TipoAcao.Gravar);
        if (retorno != "")
        {
            TempData["MsgRetornoError"] = retorno;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        if (btnSubmit != "Excluir")                
            UpdateModel(produtoPadrao);

        FlexGestor.Helpers.EntidadeBaseExt.AtribuirValores(produtoPadrao, btnSubmit);
        db.Entry(produtoPadrao).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        if (btnSubmit == "Excluir")
            return RedirectToAction("Index", controller);

        return RedirectToAction("Detalhar", controller, new { id = model.ProdutoPadraoID });
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.ProdutoPadrao


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="row">                
        @Html.TituloPagina("Visualizando Produto Padrão", "Clique para abrir a ajuda", "#help_produtoPadrao")
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoID)
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Detalhe) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Detalhe)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Detalhe, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "4" })
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica)
        <div class="controls">
            <ul id="PhonesEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
                @if (Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica)
                    {
                        Html.RenderPartial("_CustomerPhonesEditor", item);
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <p><a id="addAnother" class="small-button">AddPhone</a></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.BotaoTelaDetalhar()
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

### View Detail

```
@model FlexGestor.Models.ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica


@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ListaProdutoCaracteristica"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProdutoPadraoCaracteristicaID)

    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TipoCaracteristicaID) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TipoCaracteristicaID)
        @Html.DropDownList("TipoCaracteristicaID", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaCaracteristica, String.Empty,
                      new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Descricao) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Descricao)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <a onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();" class="small-button" style="float: left;">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Try to create the simplest version of your code that still produces this error.

Comment: Could you post the `UpdateModel` method ? The problem could be in there.

Answer (score 1):

The below line is causing the problem

`model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica = null;`

It would cause the below property to be null, but it is not a nullable type

`public int ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }`

If you want to be able to orphan records in this way, then you need to change it to a nullable int:

`public int? ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }`

Comment: It's not a proxy, it's a disconnected object, Are you sure EF will not just ignore the list?

Comment: `model.ListaProdutoCaracteristica = null;` one was my test, taking it also gives the problem. If `public int? ProdutoPadraoID { get; set; }`  this erro message: `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProdutoPadraoID', table 'testes.dbo.PRODUTOPADRAOCARACTERISTICA'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.` I'm guessing you have to find a way to decouple the items in the list. But how to do this?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve. The error you are getting now is because you have changed the model but the db field mapped to the property does not allow nulls. You can avoid the error by not setting the property to null. Why are you doing this? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @BenRobinson I'm showing on the screen a 'ProdutoPadrao` object and its children using the `class` ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica` begincollectionitem`. The problem is that while trying to save the object that has some record of `ProdutoPadraoCaracteristica` is giving initial. What should I do not to give error?

Comment: Im still not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to avoid the error you can update the database to allow nulls or don't set the property to null. Both will avoid the error bit i cant tell whether either will give you your desired result.